Show native ios logs in flutter release mode
I want to show native ios logs (originating from a flutter package and created using os_log) however they only show in flutter debug mode, but I need to use release mode (I want to test something which happens in the background when my app is closed so I need to install the app on a physical iOS device and this can't be done in debug mode).
Is there a way to show native ios logs in flutter release mode?
